# Placing archers on wall

Tags: algorithm

I have a matrix (with 0 and 1), representing a castle wall and its surroundings.

My task is to place `n` archers on the wall in a way, that they covers as much surroundings as they can. There are two rules:

**1**: Every archer has range 1 - that means, he can shoot only on adjoining tiles (each tile has 8-neighbours), which aren't wall (friendly fire is banned in this army!).

**2**: If so happens, that multiple archers can shoot at same tile, that tile only counts as one.

I am struggling to find effective solution for this - partially because I don't know, if there exist any in polynomial time. **Is there any?**

I guess first step is to use BFS algorithm to rate every tile on matrix, but I don't know how to effectivelly solve it with second rule. The brute force solution is quite simple - rate every position and then try all of them, which would be very very uneffective - I think O(|possible placements|^n), which isn't nice.

**Simple example:**

The grey-colored tiles represents the wall. Numbers inside a tiles are representing coverage of archer placed on that tile. Just to be sure, I added orange ones, which are representing coverage of archer standing on tile b2. And the last information - correct solution for this is b2 and b6, with coverage of 14. It cannot be b2 and b4, because they covers only 11 tiles.

[image: sample test case]

Comment: Do you have any sample test case? Adjoining tiles are in the 4-neighborhood or the 8-neighborhood?

Comment: You can relatively easily express the problem as an ILP, which will give you a efficient way to find a solution in practical terms. But it doesn't guarantee polynomial time.

Comment: @JohnBupit Adjoining tiles are 8-neighbourhood. I'll draw a simple test case and post it here.

Comment: @JohnBupit I added that test case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see how the problem can be solved in guaranteed polynomial time, but you can express the problem as an integer linear program, which can be solved using an ILP solver such as GLPK.

Let `c[i]` be 0-1 integer variables, one for each square of surrounding. These will represent whether this square is covered by at least one archer.

Let `a[i]` be 0-1 integer variables, one for each square of castle wall. These will represent whether an archer stands on this square.

There must be at most `n` archers: `sum(a[i] for i in castle walls) <= n`

The `c[i]` must be zero if there's no adjacent archer: `sum(a[j] for j castle wall adjacent to i) >= c[i]`

The optimization target is to maximize `sum(c[i])`.

For example, suppose this is the map (where `.` is surrounding, and `#` castle wall), and want to place two archers.

```
....
.###
....
```

Then we have this ILP problem, where all the variables are 0-1 integer variables.

```
maximize (
      c[0,0] + c[0,1] + c[0,2] + c[0,3]
    + c[1,0]
    + c[2,0] + c[2,1] + c[2,2] + c[2,3])

such that:

a[1,1] + a[1,2] + a[1,3] <= 2

c[0,0] <= a[1,1]
c[0,1] <= a[1,1] + a[1,2]
c[0,2] <= a[1,1] + a[1,2] + a[1,3]
c[0,3] <= a[1,2] + a[1,3]
c[1,0] <= a[1,1]
c[2,0] <= a[1,1]
c[2,1] <= a[1,1] + a[1,2]
c[2,2] <= a[1,1] + a[1,2] + a[1,3]
c[2,3] <= a[1,2] + a[1,3]
```

Comment: Does this scale easily to cases with multiple archers? I can imagine that e.g. equations such as 
`a[1,1] + a[1,2] <= 1` and `c[0,2] <= a[1,1] + a[1,2]` might be thrown off in a scenario with 3 archers. Could you show the setting for a slightly less trivial example?

Comment: @Joost you're right -- now it's less trivial and a better example.

Comment: Right. As I was fearing: does this account for the second rule? I mean, `c[0,2] <= a[1,1] + a[1,2] + a[1,3]` seems to suggest that `c[0, 2]` can actually be valued at `2`.

Comment: @Joost The variables are constrained to take values 0 and 1 -- that's what I meant by "0-1 integer variables". This is a feature built in to most ILP solvers since it's so common, but if not you can always add the constraint by hand: `0 <= c[i,j] <= 1`.